# Fitting a line matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, database, qt, pyqt

I have my goodness of fit line. However, I want to shift the fit line down to touch the lowest leftmost point on the graph.

[image: I would like to accomplish this]

Here is my minimally reproduceable example below and what I have come up with thus far.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import uncertainties.unumpy as unp
import uncertainties as unc

class FatigueCurve:
    def __init__(self) -> None:

        # make the data
        y = [862.0,716.0,862.0,793.0,690.0,690.0,621.0,621.0,690.0,552.0,552.0,552.0]
        x = [1.0,1.0,11.0,160.0,563.0,680.0,4130.0,7528.0,9768.0,77843.0,115530.0,394498.0]

        ...

        Code for goodness of fit

        ...

        x1y1 = min(px),max(nom)
        x2y2 = max(px),min(nom)
        
        crossProducts = []
        for x,y in zip(cycles, stress):
            x3y3 = (x,y)
            crossProducts.append((x2y2[0] - x1y1[0]) * (x3y3[1] - x1y1[1]) - (x2y2[1] - x1y1[1]) * (x3y3[0] - x1y1[0]))
        closestToZero = np.inf
        for item in crossProducts:
            if item < closestToZero:
                closestToZero = item

        # this is where I would like to shift the goodness of fit line down to closestToZero

        # plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        ax.semilogx(x, y, 'bo', label='data')
        ax.plot(px, nom, c='red', label='curve fit')

        plt.show()

    def powerLaw(self, S, A, B):
        return A * np.power(S,B)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FatigueCurve()
```

What I would like to do now is shift the line down using the greatest cross product.

Comment: Why do you want the fitted curve go through the lowest point?

Comment: Not sure honestly. Just the task I have been given and don't really know what to search for specifically to learn about it.

Comment: I tried to answer to your problem even if I don't understand the goal :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your fitted curve go through the lowest point, you can use the `sigma` parameter. `sigma` can act as weight to "force" the fitted curve. What you need is to fix the `std` to 1 for this particular point. In fact, you fix the degree of freedom to fit the curve.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import uncertainties.unumpy as unp
import uncertainties as unc

class FatigueCurve:
    def __init__(self) -> None:

        # make the data
        y = [125,190,335,279,212,186,186,345,345,345,276,276,190,207,276,207]
        x = [1996768,593319,674,17700,138596,1612585,920132,2080,1244,779,19034,38474,18865901,3000000,21100,8266515]

        # HERE: force the weights
        w = np.zeros_like(y) + np.std(y)
        w[np.argmin(y)] = 1

        # HERE: use sigma=w as parameter of curve_fit
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(self.powerLaw, x, y, sigma=w, maxfev=1000)
        a,b = unc.correlated_values(popt, pcov)
        px = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(x))
        py = a*np.power(px,b)
        nom = unp.nominal_values(py)
        print(px)
        print(py)

        # plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        ax.semilogx(x, y, 'bo', label='data')
        ax.plot(px, nom, c='red', label='curve fit')

        plt.show()

    def powerLaw(self, S, A, B):
        return A * np.power(S,B)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FatigueCurve()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the line stays beneath all other points on the graph?

Comment: so the line goes beneath the points ~10^3, ~350?

Comment: `curve_fit` is not  magic. You can also use `numpy.polyfit` but you have to study your data points and evaluate the degree of the fitting polynomial. Maybe it does not make sense to do that if the lowest point is an outlier (which seems to be the case here)

Comment: Okay. I will take a look but I don't think it will work either as you have hinted. Thank you for the response though it has helped me to understand how curve_fit and sigma work

Comment: Your answer does give me a reasonable fit thank you.